# gpg batch: created an empty secring file

Tags: gpg

I'm using the following command to generate a gpg key

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /tmp/gpg.txt << EOF
%echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
Key-Type: DSA
Key-Length: 1024
Subkey-Type: ELG-E
Subkey-Length: 1024
Name-Real: test
Name-Comment: test
Name-Email: test@test.org
Expire-Date: 0
Passphrase: test
%pubring test.pub
%secring test.sec
%commit
%echo done
EOF

gpg2 --armor --batch --gen-key /tmp/gpg.txt
rm -f /tmp/gpg.txt
```

It works partially. Only `test.pub` is created, and `test.sec` is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve it in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I've found a solution. According to ghe [GnuPG documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html), the

```
%secring test.sec
```

is now deprecated:

```
%secring filename

    This option is a no-op for GnuPG 2.1 and later.

    See the previous subsection “Ephemeral home directories”.
```

This because they have changed the way private keys are stored, as described in this [other documentation page](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Ephemeral-home-directories.html).